# Node.js: MySQL query with multiple variables

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm writing a **node/express** application, using **mysql** as a database.

One question upfront, that i can't really figure out yet: Is it possible to make multiple querys in one route?

Nevertheless, my problem is, that i want to use multiple variables in the database-query as follows, which does not work.

```
router.get('/:route_name', (req, res) => {

  const route_name = req.params.route_name;
  const route_name_join = req.params.route_name+".comp_id";
  const queryhelper = [route_name, route_name_join];
  const dbquery = "SELECT * FROM ? INNER JOIN users ON ? = users.id;";

  sqldb.query(dbquery, queryhelper, function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;

    res.render('categories/category',{
      items : result
    });

    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
  });
```

I'm expecting to, for example in case of

.../categories/customers

`"SELECT * FROM customers INNER JOIN users ON customers.comp_id = users.id;"`.

If i type in exactly that into dbquery, it does work, but as soon as i'm doing it using '?', i get an error that i'm having a mistake in my mysql syntax at

`"SELECT * FROM 'customers' INNER JOIN users ON 'customers.comp_id' = users.id;"`

I assume that there is a problem at customers.comp_id, but i simply can't figure out how to fix it.

Comment: You can't use parameters for table and column names, only for expressions.

Comment: In general, if you need to substitute a table or column name dynamically, it's often a signal that there's a problem with your database design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to perform string substitution for this. Parameters can only be used for expressions -- they're replaced with the supplied value as a literal. You can't use a parameter to supply a table or column name.

So do:

```
const dbquery = `SELECT * FROM ${route_name} INNER JOIN users ON ${route_name_join} = users.id;`;
```

If these variables are coming from user input, make sure you whitelist them before using them in the query, to prevent SQL-injection.

Comment: Hi Barmar, your answer worked for me, thank you very much! You might be right with your suggestion, that my database design could be the problem, as i'm quite unexperienced. I'll definitely try to figure out a better solution now.